# Generate permutation among several lists

Tags: python, list, permutation

Suppose that I have A=[a,b,c], B=[d,e], C=[f,g] and I want all possible permutations among A,B and C.

Ex:

```
 [[a,d,f],[a,d,g],[b,d,f],[b,d,g],[c,d,f],[c,d,g],[a,e,f],[a,e,g],[b,e,f],[b,e,g],[c,e,f],[c,e,g]]
```

How do I do that in python?

Comment: check out the itertools library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is with itertools.product:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(A,B,C))
[('a', 'd', 'f'),
 ('a', 'd', 'g'),
 ('a', 'e', 'f'),
 ('a', 'e', 'g'),
 ('b', 'd', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd', 'g'),
 ('b', 'e', 'f'),
 ('b', 'e', 'g'),
 ('c', 'd', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd', 'g'),
 ('c', 'e', 'f'),
 ('c', 'e', 'g')]
```